# Cookie not deleting in Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a cloud web site (Azure Website) that reads some data from a cookie to keep track of user activities.

Suddenly my SignOut method isn't working, and I cannot figure out why. I'm following recommended procedure to clear out cookies.

Here's what happens

User clicks signout:

```
public void SignOut()
{
    var httpCookie = Request.Cookies["cookiename"];
    if (httpCookie != null)
    {
        httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
    }
    Response.Redirect("/");
}
```

Upon inspection of the cookie at `Response.Cookies.Add` variable `httpCookie` does in fact show a date of one day before today.

When I get back to the home page after hitting `Response.Redirect`, the cookie is the same as it was before:

```
var httpCookie = Request.Cookies["cookiename"];
if (httpCookie != null)
{
    //pick up where we left off
}
```

Not allowing my users to sign out is a bit of a downer. Everything looks great, so where do I look to find an error?

**UPDATE**

The `Response.Cookies.Add` method seems to fail right away. If I change this to:

```
public void SignOut()
{
    var httpCookie = Request.Cookies["cookiename"];
    if (httpCookie != null)
    {
        var deadCookie = new HttpCookie("cookiename");
        deadCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Cookies.Add(deadCookie);
        var httpCookie2 = Request.Cookies["cookiename"];
    }
    Response.Redirect("/");
}
```

The value of `httpCookie2` is still wrong. Don't know if this helps/

Comment: Does replacing `Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie)` with `Response.SetCookie(httpCookie)` help? As for your update, you are modifying the cookie in the response, do not expect it to change in request just right after. It would change only after the roundtrip to the client and back again.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to change anything. And if I wait a minute and refresh the home page, the cookie is still there.

Comment: Sniff the http traffic with fiddler. See how many cookies you have in the response, what is the expiry date sent from server. Then, in the upcoming request see if the cookie is still there.

Comment: Going to pose a new question. It seems the initial cookie is not coming through properly, and the domain is getting left out and the date is corrupted.